# Weil Reciprocity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

This question comes from Silverman's AEC, exercise 2.11, self-study. The goal is to prove Weil reciprocity: if $C$ is a smooth curve over $K$ and $f,g$ are nonzero functions in the function field with disjoint supports, then

$$f(\operatorname{div} g) = g(\operatorname{div} f)$$

where for a divisor $D = \sum_P n_P P$,

$$f(D):= \prod_P f(P)^{n_P}$$

Now, we are told to first prove this for $\mathbb P^1$, which is easy to do. We are then asked to prove it for general $C$ by considering $f,g$ as maps $f, g: C \to \mathbb P^1$ to reduce to the above case. Here is all I have been able to do thus far, and it seems to lead to a mess of calculations quickly instead of reducing the problem to a simpler case. Let $\cdot^*$ indicate pullback of function fields, and let $\cdot_*$ denote pushforward, which is the inverse of pullback composed with the norm map. Let $i : \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ the identity map. Then, using established properties of these operations:

$$f(\operatorname{div}g) = f(g^* \operatorname{div} i) = (g_* f)\operatorname{div} i = (g_* f)(0 - \infty) = (g_*f)(0)\cdot(g_*f)(\infty)^{-1} = (g^{*-1} \circ N(f))(0) \cdot (g^{*-1} \circ N(f))(\infty)^{-1} $$

From here, if my extension of function fields is Galois, I can replace $N(f)$ by $\prod_\sigma \sigma(f)$. From there, I am stuck. This doesn't seem to be reducing the problem down.

Here are two sources I looked at:

https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.782/ProblemSet9.pdf

which seems to indicate the result should follow simply from known results about pushforward, pullback and divisors, and

[http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~djao/co690.2007/weil.pdf](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edjao/co690.2007/weil.pdf)

whose Theorem 2.1 seems <s>false and</s> unfamiliar <s>(I think it should say that a divisor on an elliptic curve is principal iff its degree is $0$, although one direction of that is not clear to me</s>, and whose approach seems more general than intended.

Comment: You're alleging that a document on my web site states a false theorem. Them's fighting words! I will point out that your proposed "fix" is incorrect: $(P)-(O)$ has degree zero for any $P \in E$, but this divisor is never principal unless $P$ happens to equal $O$. Indeed, the distinction between degree 0 divisors and principal divisors is CRUCIAL in the theory of elliptic curves.

Comment: I was simply proposing that it seemed wrong; I cannot make the claim that it is. The theorem says that to be principal you have to not only be of degree 0 but be the  0 divisor unless I am misunderstanding the notation. Surely not only the zero divisor is principal?

Comment: An example of a nonzero principal divisor on an elliptic curve is the following: $2(P)-2(O)$, where $P \in E$ is any point of the form $(e,0)$. This calculation is given in Silverman Example II.3.3.

Comment: By the way, Silverman Theorem III.3.5 contains another statement (and proof) of the result that you are proposing is wrong.

Comment: @djao exactly. But what I'm saying is that the theorem as you have typed it up seems to suggest that being principal is the same as having degree zero and also being the zero divisor. Maybe it's just the notation though that I can't get past..

Comment: To be clear, the theorem is not "as I have typed it up" -- the author of the document is clearly listed in the document, and the author is not me. The document is hosted on my web site, but I did not write it. That said, in what way does the notation from that document not match the notation in Silverman?

Comment: I was thrown off by the fact that there was no reference for the theorem and the notation was not explained. Weil reciprocity is asked of the reader well before III.3.5 in Silverman, so I had not run into the bracket notation and assumed that this was simply the divisor. My apologies for my imprecision and lack of due diligence.